# How can I refresh homestead for a new site in my environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I'm running Laravel 4 on my development machine (Mac) with homestead and enjoying it thus far but having trouble when adding a new site.  The problem is that I add lines like this for a new site in my ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml file:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: listingnaples.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/listingnaples.com/public

    - map: videocraftersusa.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/videocraftersusa.com/
```

Then, my /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
# MY SITES
192.168.10.10 listingnaples.dev
192.168.10.10 videocraftersusa.dev
192.168.10.10 laneyandchris.dev
```

If i go in and do a `homestead destroy` followed by `homestead up` I can access any of those new sites. That deletes my databases though and really sets me back.  How do I "refresh" so to speak?  If I add myawesomesite.dev to my /etc/hosts, how can I have homestead pick it up?

I tried `homestead --provision` but that isn't a recognized command.

For what it's worth, in my ~/.homestead/ directory, I do not have a VagrantFile.  Not sure where that's at so I can't run a vagrant provision either.

Answer (score 11):

You can also reload the box and the settings

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

This reload the box and see if there are changes, if that's the case it will make the changes while reloading

Answer (score 8):

I just ssh using `homestead ssh` and then add this line

```
serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public/directory
```

where you replace domain.app to your app name, the same you use on your yaml file and your path to your new public site directory, then just `homestead up` and you could see it active.

Comment: This approach will work if you don't want to provision the virtual machine and delete all databases. +1 because of that.

Answer (score 3):

Try run `vagrant global-status`. You'll see the list of running boxes at this time, like this:

```
MacBook-Pro-lancedikson:~ lancedikson$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state   directory
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9710b02  default virtualbox running /Users/lancedikson/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead

The above shows information about all known Vagrant environments
on this machine. This data is cached and may not be completely
up-to-date. To interact with any of the machines, you can go to
that directory and run Vagrant, or you can use the ID directly
with Vagrant commands from any directory. For example:
"vagrant destroy 1a2b3c4d"
```

That's all. Now run `vagrant provision 9710b02` and it will be provisioned.

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel 5 and more importantly Homestead 2.0, just run:

```
homestead up
```

Then:

```
homestead provision
```

Comment: ...do you perhaps mean `homestead up` and `vagrant provision` (not `homestead provision`)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `vagrant provision` anyway from the same directory where `Homestead.yaml` is.

Comment: That gives me the following:  A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it correctly following [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)?

Comment: I can't see the new `databases:` option in your `Homestead.yaml`, is it maybe not a v2.0? In that case you shouldn't even have the `homestead` command...

Comment: I just followed Jeffrey Way's tutorial step by step.  I have a databases section in my Homestead.yaml.  I just only posted the portion regarding the sites.

Comment: Got it! The `Vagrantfile` should be located in `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/`.

Comment: I've tried at ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/ but it says ==> default: VM not created. Moving on...

Answer (score 2):

You can run:

```
homestead up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `Homestead.yaml` in `~/.homestead/` and in `~/Homestead/`.

I am not sure if the default location changed or that I changed it manually (maybe because I did not like the hidden dir), but make sure you don't have multiple `Homestead.yaml` files. I now symlinked them so I can not confuse myself any further.

But normally, `homestead provision` or `homestead up --provision` (when it was turned off) should do.